# Windows Workflow 4 Versioning

Tags: c#, workflow

I've developed a framework for our organisation centered around the use of Windows Workflow 4 and have found issues when it comes to deploying patches to workflows in that any existing persisted workflows can't be correlated again if we deploy an updated version of the workflow used.  Even if we just tweak internals between a ReceiveAndReply message without adjusting the contract it still orphans the persisted WF.  There will be times where we want to have multiple versions of a single workflow in the event that a policy changes for all new cases, but existing ones follow the previous version.

So from what I've read Workflow 4.5 does exactly this stuff straight out of the box, but I'm this system runs on an accredited network and .NET 4.5 is currently not certified for use and therefore not an option in my case.  I know that K2 Blackpearl has it's own versioning support for WF, although K2 isn't something we can introduce, so does anyone know of any other options to achieve quasi side by side versioning of workflows? 
Using as close to out of the box .NET 4 components is preferable due to licencing and minimizing the need for further certification.

Thanks,

Steve